# How to handle SaveAs PopUp in IE in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, watin, user32

I have some program that login to webSite and trying to download file,right now i am using WatIn and User32 FindWindowEx to find the SaveAs dialog and send PostMessage with tab and enter to press Save button

```
MainPopUp = browserToRun.hWnd.ToInt32();
int currChild = FindWindowEx(MainPopUp, 0, ClassName, WindowName);
PostMessage(currChild, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 2);
PostMessage(currChild, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ENTER, 2);
```

this works,but not all the time.

This is secured webSite sow i cant see the DownloadUrl and i can't use

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] static extern Int32 URLDownloadToFile(Int32 pCaller, string szURL, string szFileName, Int32 dwReserved, Int32 lpfnCB);

int response = URLDownloadToFile(0, browserToRun.Button(Find.ById("btnExcelExport")).Url, @"C:\Users\vladimirp\VN.xls", 0, 0);
```

I need some mothed that can handle this PopUp dialog,and with out UI,because the User Pc can be locked,sow this have to work even if user windows is lock.

*I dont see the downloadURL sow WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(url,Path) will not work

Do any one know how to handle IE save dialog? .Net c#

Comment: I've been dealing with the same problem for the past year and I haven't found a solution to it yet. I have a dedicated station for that with a user logged in so the process can download the file. AFAIK as long as you have the IE user UI you'll need the user to be logged on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Handling File Download PopUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638359/click-on-save-or-saveas-dialog-of-file-download)  post. However the solution in that post requires an active session of  desktop.