# Click on Save or SaveAs dialog of file download

Tags: c#, watin

I have seen couple of question posted on this topic but none of the solution worked that's why I am posting it again.

I am using WatIn to automate the testing of my website. Using IE 11. I have to download and save the file, but I am not able to click the save or saveas button of the download window. I tried FileDownloadHandler of WatIn but it didn't worked.
I am not limited to WatIn only solutions. It could be anything thing which I can use in my C# code will be acceptable

```
FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler();
browser.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);
browser.Image(Find.ByAlt("Download.Csv")).Ancestor("a").ClickNoWait();
fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(40);
fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that represent a security risk by allowing websites to automatically download files to the a user's machine without their input? For that reason, it may be something that the browser simply won't allow easily.

Comment: John the above solution is for testing of the website. check out WatIn library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using IE 11 and was able to download and close the dialog box

[Automate of file download in IE 11 using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643273/automate-of-file-download-in-ie-11-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

WatiN does not completely interact with Windows controls and help in windows is very little. I had the same problem in handling the windows controls as we had multiple versions of IE. IE 9.0 and higher have different file handling when compared to <= IE 8.0 version. The below works fine for IE 9.0 and higher.
Please make sure proper references are added (refer using's).

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using WatiN.Core;
using WatiN.Core.Native.Windows;

namespace TestFramework.Util
{
  public static class WindowsHelper
  {
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Download IE file.
    /// </summary>        
    /// <param name="action">Action can be Save/Save As/Open/Cancel.</param>
    /// <param name="path">Path where file needs to be saved (for Save As function).</param>
    public static void DownloadIEFile(string action, string path = "", string regexPatternToMatch = "")
    {
        Browser browser = null;
        if (Utility.Browser != null) // Utility.Browser is my WatiN browser instance.
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(regexPatternToMatch))
            {
                browser = Utility.Browser;
            }
            else
            {
                Utility.Wait(() => (browser = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regexPatternToMatch)))) != null);
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            return;
        }

        // If doesn't work try to increase sleep interval or write your own waitUntill method
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        // See information here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx)
        Window windowMain = null;
        Utility.Wait(() => (windowMain = new Window(NativeMethods.GetWindow(browser.hWnd, 5))).ProcessID != 0);

        TreeWalker trw = new TreeWalker(Condition.TrueCondition);
        AutomationElement mainWindow = trw.GetParent(AutomationElement.FromHandle(browser.hWnd));

        Window windowDialog = null;
        Utility.Wait(() => (windowDialog = new Window(NativeMethods.GetWindow(windowMain.Hwnd, 5))).ProcessID != 0);

        windowDialog.SetActivate();
        AutomationElementCollection amc = null;
        Utility.Wait(() => (amc = AutomationElement.FromHandle(windowDialog.Hwnd).FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)).Count > 1);

        foreach (AutomationElement element in amc)
        {
            // You can use "Save ", "Open", ''Cancel', or "Close" to find necessary button Or write your own enum
            if (element.Current.Name.Equals(action))
            {
                // If doesn't work try to increase sleep interval or write your own waitUntil method
                // WaitUntilButtonExsist(element,100);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                AutomationPattern[] pats = element.GetSupportedPatterns();

                // Replace this for each if you need 'Save as' with code bellow
                foreach (AutomationPattern pat in pats)
                {
                    // '10000' button click event id 
                    if (pat.Id == 10000)
                    {
                        InvokePattern click = (InvokePattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(pat);
                        click.Invoke();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (element.Current.Name.Equals("Save") && action == "Save As")
            {
                AutomationElementCollection bmc = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Automation.ControlViewCondition);
                InvokePattern click1 = (InvokePattern)bmc[0].GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(10000));
                click1.Invoke();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                AutomationElementCollection main = mainWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
                foreach (AutomationElement el in main)
                {
                    if (el.Current.LocalizedControlType == "menu")
                    {
                        // First array element 'Save', second array element 'Save as', third second array element   'Save and open'
                        InvokePattern clickMenu = (InvokePattern)
                                    el.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[1].GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(10000));
                        clickMenu.Invoke();
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        ControlSaveDialog(mainWindow, path);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Control for save dialog.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mainWindow">Main window.</param>
    /// <param name="path">Path.</param>
    private static void ControlSaveDialog(AutomationElement mainWindow, string path)
    {
        // Obtain the save as dialog
        var saveAsDialog = mainWindow
                            .FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                                       new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Save As"));
        // Get the file name box
        var saveAsText = saveAsDialog
                .FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                           new AndCondition(
                               new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "File name:"),
                               new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)))
                .GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;

        // Fill the filename box 
        saveAsText.SetValue(path);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Utility.PressKey("LEFT");
        Utility.PressKey("LEFT");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Find the save button
        var saveButton =
                saveAsDialog.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                new AndCondition(
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Save"),
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button)));

        // Invoke the button
        var pattern = saveButton.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        pattern.Invoke();
    }

    #endregion
}
}


public static class Utility
{       
    public static IE Browser { get; set; }

    // Wait specified number of seconds
    public static void Wait(int seconds)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(seconds * 1000);
    }

    // Wait for condition to evaluate true, timeout after 30 seconds
    public static void Wait(Func<bool> condition)
    {
        int count = 0;

        while (!condition() && count < 30)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            count++;
        }
    }

    //Send tab key press to browser
    public static void PressTab()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
    }

    //Send specified key press to browser
    public static void PressKey(string keyname)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{" + keyname.ToUpper() + "}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks sham for the code. Can you please share the utility,Navigation class as well because I am unable to compile the code